List all folder names under an AWS S3 bucket in C# ASP.NET
I have a method that will return a list of all objects with in a specific folder in an S3 bucket:
public static async Task<List<string>> GetAvailableDatasetsList(AmazonS3Client s3Client, string bucketName)
        {
            try
            {
                ListObjectsV2Response response = await s3Client.ListObjectsV2Async(new ListObjectsV2Request
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Prefix = "folderName1",
                    StartAfter = "folderName1"
                });
                Console.WriteLine($"Size: {response.S3Objects.Count}");
                return response.S3Objects
                    .Select(o => o.Key.Split('/')[1])
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToList();  
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error retrieving list from S3: " + e.Message);
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }

My S3 bucket structure:
bucketName
     - folderName1
          - subfolder1
               - *this folder have more than 1000 items[images]
          - subfolder2
               - *this folder have more than 1000 items[images]
          - subfolder3
               - *this folder have more than 1000 items[images]

What I want to accomplish is to return the list:
subFolder1
subFolder2
subFolder3

For some reason, my current method will only return subFolder2. I don't know why. And the response.S3Objects.Count returns 1000, but the Count of the returned list is only 1.
Can anyone help me fix this? than you
UPDATE
I was able to accomplish the required output by pagination. The issue now is that there are subfolders that are added multiple time in the list.
Updated Method:
public static async Task<List<string>> GetAvailableDatasetsList(AmazonS3Client s3Client, string bucketName)
        {
            try
            {
                List<string> customUploads = new List<string>();
                string continuationToken = null;

                do
                {
                    ListObjectsV2Response response = await s3Client.ListObjectsV2Async(new ListObjectsV2Request
                    {
                        BucketName = bucketName,
                        Prefix = "custom-uploads",
                        StartAfter = "custom-uploads",
                        ContinuationToken = continuationToken
                    });

                    customUploads.AddRange(response.S3Objects
                        .Select(o => o.Key.Split('/')[1])
                        .Distinct());

                    continuationToken = response.NextContinuationToken;
                }
                while (continuationToken != null);

                return customUploads;
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error retrieving list from S3: " + e.Message);
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }


If you have more 1000 files in each subfolder, you would call list api recursively until the list api return 0 files or less than 1000 files.

I was able to accomplish the required output by pagination already. The issue now is that there are subfolders that are added multiple time in the list.
:updated code above

Set Delimiter to / in your ListObjectsV2Request object, and look at the resulting CommonPrefixes member of the ListObjectsV2Response response.
